# Hive table is read multiple times when using spark.sql and union

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a single Hive table that is used in multiple subsequent spark.sql queries.

Each stage shows a HiveTableScan, that is not necessary as the table only needs to be read once.

How can I avoid this?

Here is a simplified example that replicates the problem

Create an example table:-

```
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS default")
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.data")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.data(value INT)")
spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE default.data VALUES(1)")
```

Run multiple queries that build on the previous dataframe:-

```
query1 = spark.sql("select value from default.data")
query1.createOrReplaceTempView("query1")

query2 = spark.sql("select max(value)+1 as value from query1").union(query1)
query2.createOrReplaceTempView("query2")

query3 = spark.sql("select max(value)+1 as value from query2").union(query2)
query3.createOrReplaceTempView("query3")

spark.sql("select value from query3").show()
```

Expected output is:-

```
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    2|
|    1|
+-----+
```

Comment: I guess what I am expecting here is Spark to read the Hive table once and calculate the subsequent dataframe in a nice in-memory pipeline. What is see if the table being queried multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDITED***

you can use **cacheTable**(String tableName) ?

try this:

```
query1 = spark.sql("select value from default.data")
query1.createOrReplaceTempView("query1")

spark.sqlContext().cacheTable("query1")

query2 = spark.sql("select max(value)+1 as value from query1").union(query1)
query2.createOrReplaceTempView("query2")

spark.sqlContext().cacheTable("query2")

query3 = spark.sql("select max(value)+1 as value from query2").union(query2)
query3.createOrReplaceTempView("query3")

spark.sqlContext().cacheTable("query3")

spark.sql("select value from query3").show()
```

Using this function, Spark-Sql will cache your tables using an in-memory columnar format to minimze memory usage.
Then you can uncache the tables using **uncacheTable()** as below:

```
spark.sqlContext().uncacheTable("query1");
spark.sqlContext().uncacheTable("query2");
spark.sqlContext().uncacheTable("query3");
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried using cache() and persist(), but still see more HiveTableScans that I expect. Job 0 contains 4, and Job 1 contains 1 (3 skipped).

Comment: Hi @DinoG I think  I understand what do you need , 
I have edited my answer.
Please check it out and let me know

Comment: I get the same result as before. The UI seems to be suggesting multiple reads of the same table.